# jq: Move subset of fields under a new field

Tags: json, jq

I have JSON data files that I'd like to modify somewhat. From:

```json
{
    "alpha": "...",
    "beta": [ ... ],
    "delta": { ... },
    "gamma": "..."
}
```

to:

```json
{
    "alpha": "...",
    "epsilon" : {
        "beta": [ ... ],
        "delta": { ... }
    },
    "gamma": "..."
}
```

This is, I want to define a subset of fields that I want to extract and move into a new sub-object with a specific name. How do I perform such a task with `jq`?

Answer (score 3):

`jq '{ alpha, epsilon: { beta, delta }, gamma }' input.json > output.json`

Answer (score 2):

> define a subset of fields that I want to extract and move

Here's a programmatic way:

```
jq --argjson fields '["beta", "delta"]' '
 def project($fields): . as $in | reduce $fields[] as $k ({}; .[$k] = $in[$k]);

 .epsilon = project($fields)
 | delpaths( [$fields[]| [.]] )
 '
```